# what are the maven dependency policies on transient exclusions

Tags: maven, dependency-management

I am using Maven 3, and I have a small project with a module that depends on another module of this project. The lower one is basically the JPA entity model and the other one the REST service using it. All of them have spring-boot dependencies

I wanted to use more recent Hibernate and EhCache dependencies and sorted these out in the JPA module, excluding them, and the maven dependency:tree shows everything as I wanted it.

But when I add that module in my other module as dependency, all those excluded dependency versions are back again in my dependency tree.

Why does Maven pick the dependencies deeper in the tree branches (and excluded) before the versions I defined on first level in my module?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you defined the exclusions in the `<dependencyManagement>` section of the POM of the first module. When another module referenced the first module, these exclusions are gone, right?

What I would suggest:

If you need newer versions of a given dependency, do not use exclusions, but use `<dependencyManagement>` to define the new version. This overwrites all transitive version definitions.

Comment: no, there is no dependency management section defined. just straight dependencies and exclusions in the first module, then depending on it in the second module.